# Botón que al darle click me genere otro botón

Tags: javascript, dom

Lo que quiero hacer es que al darle "click" al botón me genere otro botón identico solo que en vez de decir "Player 1" el nombre se registre en otro botón llamado "Player 2" y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si observan la imagen verán que cuando oprimo "Player 1" el programa me permite por medio de un prompt ingresar un nombre pero entonces lo guarda en un recuadro que no me permite dar click y que además no dice "Player 2" y así sucesivamente, he intentado varias cosas pero nada me ha funcionado, espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

```
    "use strict";

const buttom = document.querySelectorAll("p");


for(let i = 0; i < buttom.length; i++) {
    buttom[i].addEventListener("click", actualizarNombre);
}




function actualizarNombre() {
  let name1 = document.createElement('p');
  name1.textContent = prompt("¿Cúal es tú nombre?");
  buttom.textContent = "Player 1: "  + name1;
  document.body.appendChild(name1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, se ve que has liado un poco las variables.
dentro de name1 pones el nombre, pero

```
var jugador=1;
function actualizarNombre() {
  let name1 = document.createElement('p');
  let gamer = prompt("¿Cúal es tú nombre?");
  name1.textContent = "Player "+(++jugador)+": " + gamer;
  document.body.appendChild(name1)
}
```

De esta manera cada vez que pulsas el botón inicial player1 se crea otro botón con el texto playerN: nombre.
Se usa una variable global jugador para saber el número a generar. Y por lo que entiendo el unico botón que genera más botones es el de Player1.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi hermano,  me funciono el código a la perfección.